# Spring HATEOAS, embed linked object in WS response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am using Spring Boot and Spring HATEOAS to build a REST API.

I have 2 simple objects. Let's say:

```
// Model
@Entity
public class Person {
    private String  name;
    private Address address;
    // ... usual methods omitted for brievity
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    // ...
}

// Repository. It exposes directly a REST service
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {}

// Application entry point
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

This simple project creates output like the following:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/persons{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "persons": [
            {
                "name": "Some name",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Fine, but I would like the application to send the Address object directly in the response. In order not to have to query the URL of the address.

Something like:

```
...
        "persons": [
            {
                "name": "Some name",
                "address": {
                    "street": "Some street name"
                    "city": "Some city name"
                }
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
...
```

Are there any configuration to do that? I could not find any configuration about it in Spring HATEOAS docs. And this is the default behavior when using only regular Spring controllers.

Comment: is address annotated with @Entity?

Comment: @ChrisDaMour Yes it is. I forgot it, I have edited my question to add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release of Spring Data REST's docs illustrate [excerpt projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpting-commonly-accessed-data). This provides an alternative default view of a collection of data.

Your use case is the exact angle it was originally designed for.

Comment: I could not test, but I marked as correct answer because it is exactly what I needed at that time

Answer (score 0):

Delete AddressRepository interface, and object Address will be embedded in json in Person class. But it will not be possible to get Address by ID